# Как выйти из двух вложенных циклов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ищу циклом текущего пользователя компьютера в локальной сети

```
def scan_Lan():
    ip_list = ['192.168.4.']
    i = 50
    while i <= 240:
        scan_ip = ip_list[0] + str(i)
        response = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", scan_ip]).wait()
        if(response == 0):
            try:
                wql = 'SELECT *  FROM Win32_computerSystem'
                c = wmi.WMI(scan_ip, user='office\admin', password='fff')
                for item in c.query(wql):
                    currentUser = str(item.UserName)
                    print(currentUser)
                    if(currentUser == "ivanov"):
                        print(scan_ip)
                        break
            except:
                   print("-")
        i += 1
    print("end")

scan_Lan()
```

Все хорошо работает, но хочу после поиска выходить полностью из цикла while, как это сделать? Поставил вот здесь

```
 print(scan_ip)
 break
```

но он по всей видимости выходит только из for, а как сделать глобальный break?

Comment: в сторону: 1- `for i in range(50, 241):` более идиоматочно чем `while`-цикл 2- можно заменить `Popen().wait()` на `subprocess.call()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`break` прекращает только вложенный цикл. Внешний цикл продолжает работать. Используйте `return`, когда результат найден в вашем случае:

```
if current_user == 'ivanov':
    return scan_ip
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так

```
    while i <= 240:
        scan_ip = ip_list[0] + str(i)
        response = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", scan_ip]).wait()
        if(response == 0):
            try:
                wql = 'SELECT *  FROM Win32_computerSystem'
                c = wmi.WMI(scan_ip, user='office\admin', password='fff')
                for item in c.query(wql):
                    currentUser = str(item.UserName)
                    print(currentUser)
                    if(currentUser == "ivanov"):
                        print(scan_ip)
                        break
                else: 
                  i += 1  # сюда зайдет, если цикл завершился полностью(то есть не было найдено)
                  print("end")
                  continue;
            except:
                   print("-")
        break; # сюда попадем и прервем большой цикл, если во внутреннем был найден объект
```

Вот более простой пример для понимания

```
for x in xrange(10):
    for y in xrange(10):
        for z in xrange(10):
            print x,y,z
            if x*y*z == 30:
                break # прерываем внутренний цикл
        else:
            continue # продолжаем, если внутренний цикл не был прерван
        break # внутренний цикл был прерван, прерываем и этот цикл
    else:
        continue
    break
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте флаг (булево значение) для выхода из циклов. При входе в условие  currentUser == "ivanov" меняйте его значение на положительное, делайте break, а в основном цикле установите условие while i <= 240 and not result, тогда цикл будет завершен, как только result станет истиной.

Глобального break, для выхода из всех циклов, не существует.

Answer (score 0):

a:

```
list_ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
check = True

while check:
    for v in list_:
        if v == 3:
            check = False
            break
        else:
            print(v)
```

b:

```
list_ = [1, 2, 3, 4]

try:
    while True:
        for v in list_:
            if v == 3:
                raise UserWarning
            else:
                print(v)
except UserWarning:pass
```

1

2