# Как выйти из цикла if в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Скажите пожалуйста как выйти из цикла в питоне? Срочно! (если понадобится код то вот

```
s = input().split()
a = int(s[0]) 
b = int(s[1])
m = min(a, b)
for i in range(m):
  o = m - i
  if a % o == 0 and b % o == 0:
    print(o)
```

надо после print(o)выйти из цикла

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как выйти из цикла python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549989/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0-python)

Comment: Просто добавьте break в условии после print

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, не дубликат, там другая ситуация - два вложенных цикла.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Теперь бы еще узнать как сделать так чтобы этот код всегда работал меньше чем за 1 секунд)

Comment: Как минимум, строка o = m - i лишняя. Вы получите O в диапазоне от m до 0. То есть значения, по которым и так проходите в цикле. Уберите лишнюю переменную и используйте i

Comment: a = 456789 b = 567891 if a > b: a, b = b, a for i in range(1,a): if a % i == 0 and b % i == 0: print(i)

Comment: Как это относится к проблеме, озвученной в вопросе?

Comment: "Теперь бы еще узнать как сделать так чтобы этот код всегда работал меньше чем за 1 секунд) "

Comment: Принципиально код в этом ответе ничем не отличается от кода в вопросе. При больших a и b он будет так же медленно работать, как и код из вопроса.

Comment: @bratlukandr, если вам нужно посчитать НОД, используйте [алгоритм Евклида](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0). Вот тут можно посмотреть реализацию: https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/60131/ .

Comment: Ну так поправьте, для этого этот сайт

Comment: Мне нет смысла править ответ, не относящийся к вопросу. А правильный ответ в любом случае уже дан.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `break` для выхода из цикла.
Используйте `return` для выхода из функции.

Answer (score 0):

Можно оформить как функция и добавить return для выхода

```
def www():
    s = input().split() 
    a = int(s[0]) 
    b = int(s[1])
    m = min(a, b)
    for i in range(m):
        o = m - i
        if a % o == 0 and b % o == 0:
            print(o)
            return
www()
```